# Router understanding issue with Ember 1.0 RC6

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The following code worked fine with RC4 but it doesn't work with RC6. `index.html#/users/1/edit` doesn't fill the form to edit the user entry. Can anybody tell me what I have to change to get this working with the new router?

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
  })
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

App.UserEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor("user")
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'users' });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    if (model.get('isNew') == false) {
      var map = this.map || Ember.Map.create();
      this.map = map;
      var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
      if (map.get(model)) {
        transaction = map.get(model);
      } else {
        map.set(model, transaction);
        transaction.add(model);
      }
    }
  },

  events: {
    commitThis: function(model) {
      var map = this.map;
      var transaction = map.get(model);
      transaction.commit();
      map.remove(model);
      App.Router.router.transitionTo('users.index')
    },
    rollbackThis: function(model) {
      var map = this.map;
      var transaction = map.get(model);
      transaction.rollback();
      transaction.add(model);
      App.Router.router.transitionTo('users.index')
    }
  }
});

App.UserEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  save: function(model) {
    this.send('commitThis', model)
  },

  undo: function(model) {
    this.send('rollbackThis', model)
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Yehuda",
  lastName: "Katz"
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Dale"
}]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Userlist Demo</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
  </style>
  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="#">Demo</a>
          <div class="nav">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li>{{#linkTo 'users'}}Users{{/linkTo}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Demo Ember.js Application</h2>
    <p>
      A list of all users can be found {{#linkTo 'users'}}here{{/linkTo}}.
    </p>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='span7'>
        <table class='table table-striped'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {{#each this itemController="user"}}
              <tr {{bindAttr class="isDirty:warning"}}>
                <td>{{firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{lastName}}</td>
                <td>
                  {{#unless isNew}}
                    {{#linkTo 'user.edit' this activeClass="disabled" classNames="btn btn-small"}}<i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit{{/linkTo}}
                  {{/unless}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class='span5'>
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user/edit">
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <p><strong>First name</strong><br>{{input value=firstName type=text tabindex=1}}</p>
    <p><strong>Last name</strong><br>{{input value=lastName type=text tabindex=2}}</p>

    <p>
      <button {{action 'save' this}} {{bindAttr class=":btn :btn-small :btn-primary content.isDirty:enabled:disabled"}} tabindex=4>Save changes</button>
      <button {{action 'undo' this}} {{bindAttr class=":btn :btn-small content.isDirty:enabled:disabled"}} tabindex=5>Undo changes</button>
    </p>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/md5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is because `App.UserEditRoute.setupController` is not calling `_super`. Strange cause I thought that breaking change was back in RC4. Anyway, try this:

```
App.UserEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // ...
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Possibly related: Seems like `setupController` is saving state (`this.map`) on the route object. Surprised it works at all, for sure has potential to cause problems. Instead setupController should set properties on the local controller or model arguments, or use this.controllerFor() to access another controller.

In this case seems like a lot of code is not necessary, could just save/rollback on the model itself. So to simplify:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
  })
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

App.UserEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor("user")
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'users' });
  },

  events: {
    save: function(model) {
      model.save().then( function() {
        App.Router.router.transitionTo('users.index')
      }, function() {
        alert('save failed!');
      });
    },
    undo: function(model) {
      model.rollback();
      App.Router.router.transitionTo('users.index')
    }
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Yehuda",
  lastName: "Katz"
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Dale"
}]
```

See working example here: http://jsbin.com/ixucos/2/edit